# Returning a user-defined object from a class public function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a class called `Point2D`, and another class called `Triangle`. I want the `Triangle`
class to return the vertices of the triangle, which are `Point2D` objects, so I wrote this code:

```
Public Function vertex(vertexIndex As Single) As Point2D    

Dim ans As Point2D: Set ans = New Point2D  

Call ans.initWithPoint(vertices_(vertexIndex))   

Set vertex = ans     ' This is where the crash occurs

End Function
```

No matter how I go about it, I can't get the run-time to coerce the return of vertex into a `Point2D`.

The only solution I came up with was to pass a point as reference to a sub, which fills
it with the desired vertex. But that is highly non elegant.

Comment: what is the definition for `initWithPoint`? What is it and what does it do?